# Multiple videos on a grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I get an error when i try to show multiple(9) videos on a grid using MediaTimeline. A C++ exception is thrown. If i try to relaunch the app, sometimes it works, sometimes i get an error.

Here is my code:

```
        MediaTimeline timeline = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(videoPath, UriKind.Absolute));
        timeline.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        MediaClock clock = timeline.CreateClock();
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Clock = clock;
        player.Volume = 0;
        VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing();
        drawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        drawing.Player = player;
        DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Background = brush;
        label.Margin = new Thickness(margin);
```

Here is the exception message:

> **Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library**
>   *Runtime Error! The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team
>   for more information*

Here is the exception image:

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Runtime Error!]

Comment: Please post the *text* of your exception as text. We very strongly discourage screenshots of errors or code. Screenshots are not searchable as text, and they can't be copied as text.

Comment: thank you to answer. I already share the exception as text: Runtime Error! The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for mote information

Comment: I solved the problem by changing videos. i guess that video corrupted, so c++ library exception was thrown when i try to forse play all of them simultaneously.